# Form is not binding to correct object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I have similar objects (I'm using Model and ViewModels, where ViewModels has same properties as Model object).

When I'm editing one item, I put editors for viewmodel, and the controller that handles the update/edit, he receives the ViewModel:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(DocumentViewModel model) {
 Mapper.CreateMap < DocumentViewModel, BE.Document > ();
 BE.Document instanceOfDestination = Mapper.Map < BE.Document > (model);

 Container < BE.Document > container = BL.DocumentBL.UpdateDocument(instanceOfDestination);
 if (!container.HasErrors) {
  SetInfo("Saved!");
 } else {
  SetError(container.ErrorMessage);
 }
 return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**The problem is that this method is never reached because model binder constructs BE.Document instead of DocumentViewModel.**

Here are the values sent by browser:

```
__RequestVerificationToken:xxx-dontcare
id:36
name:test flash files
documentType.id:5
unit.id:2
reference:FLASH0016
isActive:true
isActive:false
recyclingSpan:1
selectedTopics:1
selectedTopics:2
trainer.id:615952
selectedInstallations:1
selectedInstallations:2
selectedProfessions:3
selectedProfessions:4
selectedProfessions:6
```

Here is the Controller that return VM to make the edit page:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
 var container = BL.DocumentBL.GetAllDocument(new BE.Document() {
  id = id
 });
 if (!container.HasErrors) {
  Mapper.CreateMap < BE.Document, DocumentViewModel > ();
  DocumentViewModel instanceOfDestination = Mapper.Map < DocumentViewModel > (container.Value);
  // fill values for dropdowns and co
  instanceOfDestination.FillPredefinedValuesForUser(GetAdminOrVisibilityUnits());
  return View(instanceOfDestination);
 } else {
  SetError(container.ErrorMessage);
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
}
```

And there are model and viewmodels for document:

DocumentViewModel:

```
public int id { get; set; }
[Required]
public string name { get; set; }
[Required]
public string reference { get; set; }
[Required]
[Range(0, 100)]
public int recyclingSpan { get; set; }
[Required]
public bool isActive { get; set; }

[DocumentTypeValidator("DocType is required")] // custom validator
public DocumentType documentType { get; set; }
public PersonnelAM trainer { get; set; }
public List<DocumentVersion> versions { get; set; }
public List<Installation> installations { get; set; }
public List<Profession> professions { get; set; }
public List<Topic> topics { get; set; }
public Unit unit { get; set; }

// not used for edit or create
public PersonnelAM createdBy { get; set; }
public DateTime createdOn { get; set; }
public PersonnelAM editedBy { get; set; }
public DateTime editedOn { get; set; }

// to fill dropdowns
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> documentTypeSelect { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> personnelSelect { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> installationsSelect { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> professionsSelect { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> topicTypeSelect { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> unitSelect { get; set; }


// for multi-selects - uses FillListsFromIds to fill Lists from Ids
public int[] selectedProfessions { get; set; }
public int[] selectedInstallations { get; set; }
public int[] selectedTopics { get; set; }

// For file upload
[MinLengthAttribute(1)]
public HttpPostedFileBase[] files { get; set; }
// for file get
public List<string> filesList { get; set; }
```

BE.Document

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public string reference { get; set; }
public int recyclingSpan { get; set; }
public bool isActive { get; set; }

public DocumentType documentType { get; set; }
public PersonnelAM trainer { get; set; }
public List<string> filesList { get; set; }
public List<Installation> installations { get; set; }
public List<DocumentVersion> versions { get; set; }
public List<Profession> professions { get; set; }
public List<Topic> topics { get; set; }
public Unit unit { get; set; }

public PersonnelAM createdBy { get; set; }
public DateTime createdOn { get; set; }
public PersonnelAM editedBy { get; set; }
public DateTime editedOn { get; set; }
```

Thanks to help me :-)

**EDIT :**

Here is the full Get/id Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Moderator") || SessionManager.matricule.IsDocumentCreator(id))
            {
                var container = BL.DocumentBL.GetAllDocument(new BE.Document() { id = id });
                if (!container.HasErrors)
                {
                    Mapper.CreateMap<BE.Document, DocumentViewModel>();
                    DocumentViewModel instanceOfDestination = Mapper.Map<DocumentViewModel>(container.Value);
                    // fill values for dropdowns and co
                    instanceOfDestination.FillPredefinedValuesForUser(GetAdminOrVisibilityUnits());
                    return View(instanceOfDestination);
                }
                else
                {
                    SetError(container.ErrorMessage);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SetError("Vous n'avez pas le droit d'accéder à l'édition de ce document.");
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(DocumentViewModel model)
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Moderator") || SessionManager.matricule.IsDocumentCreator(model.id))
            {
                Mapper.CreateMap<DocumentViewModel, BE.Document>();
                BE.Document instanceOfDestination = Mapper.Map<BE.Document>(model);

                Container<BE.Document> container = BL.DocumentBL.UpdateDocument(instanceOfDestination, new PersonnelAM() { id = SessionManager.matricule });
                if (!container.HasErrors)
                {
                    SetInfo("Modifications suavegardées");
                }
                else
                {
                    model.FillPredefinedValuesForUser(GetAdminOrVisibilityUnits());
                    SetError(container.ErrorMessage);
                    return View(instanceOfDestination);
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: are you passing the right model to the View while calling Edit actionmethod?

Comment: @Vini Thanks. Yes I'm using ViewModel to contrsuct the edit page, see the edited question if you want to see the controller

Comment: The `ModelBinder` DOES NOT construct `BE.Document`. The parameter in your POST method is `DocumentViewModel` so that is what is initialized. What do you mean _this method is never reached_?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have put a breakpoint in the controller, and I have a server error (white and yellow page) with this kind of message (translated from my language ( :-( ): The element passed in the dictionnary is of type BE.Document but this dicionnary requests model of type DocumentViewModel

Comment: I never doupt on you... DocumentViewModel is created when I press update button un GUI (I've put a breakpoint on it).

Comment: That means your passing an instance of `Document` to the view instead or `DocumentViewModel` but the GET code you have shown has `return View(instanceOfDestination);` and `instanceOfDestination` appears to be typeof `DocumentViewModel` so something else you have not shown us is causing the error. Have you omitted any code?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just removed a security check but I've editet the question to add full controller for get/id and the edit.cshtml, all is on the table now :-)

Comment: There is nothing in the GET method code that could throw that exception. Do you have any other code in the POST e.g. a check for `ModelState.IsValid` where you might be returning the view, but with the wrong model (i.e. `return View(instanceOfDestination);` instead of `return View(model);`)

Comment: I see that you do :). Change `return View(instanceOfDestination);` to `return View(model);` and it will work fine (`instanceOfDestination` is typeof `Document` in the POST method, not `DocumentViewModel`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke hey! I've found the issue! ... There is an error on the update, and according to the controller,I return View(instanceOfDestination) where instanceofdestination is a BE.Document ... It must be a ViewModel (as in the Edit/id)

Comment: @StephenMuecke You first :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view model is binding correctly, but in your POST method, this line of code

```
return View(instanceOfDestination);
```

is returning an instance of `Document` (as defined by `BE.Document instanceOfDestination = Mapper.Map<BE.Document>(model);`, not an instance of `DocumentViewModel` which is resulting in an exception

> The model passed in the dictionary is of type BE.Document but this dictionary requires a model of type DocumentViewModel

Change it to

```
return View(model);
```

so that the correct type is passed back to the view.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you bind the viewmodel to your view (your cshtml file), not your model, on top of your View file (for instance edit.cshtml) :

```
@model your.namespace.DocumentViewModel
```

instead of

```
@model your.namespace.BE.Document
```

But, why you use viewmodel if the viewmodel is identical to your model? why not just use your model instead

Comment: OP already is using `@model DocumentViewModel` (look at the values sent by browser!). And the code would not work is a view model was not used.

Comment: Thanks foryour help.In the view, ViewModel is references as you suggest. I'm using a ViewModel to have clean business object. My business object is ina  separate layer, and I can't use validators and Ressources files with this Business object. ViewModel is in the Web Layer and is used vor validation (data annotation) and ressources. This is why.